# Difference between 'gain optimization' and 'gains optimization'

Tags: nouns, terminology

What is the difference between *gain optimization* and *gains optimization* in a financial context?

I want to know in particular if one of those terms is better English, or if they have different meanings.

Comment: It is meant as a noun! Not as a verb, as I improperly retagged!

Comment: I think the question is: in finance, does *gain* (uncountable) mean something different from *gain* (countable)? And which one are you optimizing?

Comment: I am looking for something similar to profit optimization